# Web-Api token authentication - documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm just creating a web-api project (based on ASP.NET with C#). VS is creating this empty application with it's demo app, in order to demonstrate his capabilities. All working fine with this demo.

As part of the demo code, you will this this block in the "App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs" file:

```
    // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
    PublicClientId = "self";
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

OK. Now, let's assume that the authentication mechanism is working well. I want to add documentation to WebAPI about this "/Token" page. But, because this page is created by the code, the WebAPI documentation mechanism doesn't recognize this as part of the documentation. So, how my users should know how to login into my application?

What I'm can do in order to add this "/Token" page in my **auto generated API documentation**?

Thank you.

Comment: Look under "Adding API Documentation" here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages

Comment: This not allow me to add the "/Token" page to the documentation since it's code block, not ApiController. This exactly the problem.

Comment: did you solve your problem ?